# DHCP and read-only root filesystem

Tags: networking, dhcp, readonly, etc

When doing `ifup wlan0` on a system with `/` mounted as read-only (embedded computer), I get this error:

```
Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: wlan0  error: Read-only file system
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.1
Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

can't create /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases: Read-only file system
Listening on LPF/wlan0/80:1f:02:d3:42:b8
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/80:1f:02:d3:42:b8
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
...
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

On the other hand, when doing `ifup wlan0` with `/` mounted as read-write, no problem, an IP is succesfully attributed.

**How to make DHCP work on a read-only root filesystem?**

---

```
# /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "<myssid>"
wpa-psk "<mypasswd>"
```

Comment: `/var` and `/tmp` must be writable. If you search for "read only root filesystem", there are several guides explaining this.  You can either use a separate disk partition for `/var`, make`/var` a tmpfs partition, or use a unionfs overlay so the file system appears writable but changes are forgotten on reboot.

Answer (score 6):

Create a tmpfs partition in RAM, and then symlink /var/lib/dhcp to a directory in it.

Edit: I'll assume that you can edit your root filesystem before changing it to read-only. So:

1. Set up a tmpfs mount point with `mkdir /mnt/ramdisk && mkdir /mnt/ramdisk/var-lib-dhcp`
2. Add the tmpfs to your fstab with `tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk/var-lib-dhcp tmpfs size=10M 0 0`
3. Add a symbolic link from `/var/lib/dhcp` to `/mnt/ramdisk/var-lib-dhcp`
4. Test while file system is read/write
5. Make file system read-only, test again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: How so? It gives a clear technique that solves the problem. Perhaps it doesn't include every detail some people would like, but the OP clearly understands partition creation. (And, if it's details that you miss, you should say so.)

Comment: Thanks @DanielGriscom! I understand the "global" thing, but can you help on how to do it?
Should I add `tmpfs   /tmp/   tmpfs  0  0` in `/etc/fstab`, and then, where to set up the automatic **symlink** on boot? (I use `systemd`) ? Thanks a lot in advance.     Last think: can't I simply add this to fstab: `tmpfs   /var/lib/dhcp   tmpfs  0  0` in `/etc/fstab` ?

Comment: (I think I already tried this last thing in my previous comment, and that it didn't work)

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: Also remember to change the boot process so that it recreates the tmp subdir on every reboot, _after_ having the tmpfs tree mounted, but _before_ running dhclient.

Comment: @Basj for me adding `tmpfs /var/lib/dhcp/ tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=1M,mode=1777 0 0` in `/etc/fstab`did work :-)

Comment: @StefanKrüger Can you post a new answer (I think it's worth it) with your proposition, and add a few lines to explain how it works, why it works, etc.? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Basj done. hope it is enough background information (i don't have more at the moment)

Answer (score 4):

similar to [Daniel Griscom Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209902/77378) but a little simpler.

you can add

```
tmpfs /var/lib/dhcp/ tmpfs nodev,nosuid,size=1M,mode=1777 0 0
```

in `/etc/fstab`

this creates a temporary file-system in RAM and overwrites the directory as mount-point to this tempfs. (so if you have files there from earlier they are not available)

with this you don't need to manage the symlinks and so on...
and 1M for the size should be enough for some embedded board dhcp information.
this is also needed if you want to create an AccessPoint with DHCP server (the lease information is stored in the same directory for the server.)

remember to first remount with write access `mount -o remount,rw /` (as root) - and when you are done with the changes remount write only (`mount -o remount,ro /`) or reboot..

my original source for this tmpfs configuration string was [this short guide on *Prepare the microSD for the final application*](https://www.acmesystems.it/save_microsd)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have a tmpfs mount point, for instance /run, /var/run or /tmp, a very simple approach is executing,

`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dhcp/`

and

`sudo ln -s /run /var/lib/dhcp`

The first one will remove your `/var/lib/dhcp` database directory, the second will create a link to `/run`. Or you can make the link to `/tmp` or `/var/run`.

You will need to remount your filesystem read-write in order to execute the above changes.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem too, and creating a read-write location for /var/lib/dhcp is not enough.

I had to do the following two things :

trick /sbin/dhclient-script to tell it that / is on a read-only filesystem by adding a commented entry to /etc/fstab :

```
# The following line is here only to tell dhclient that we are readonly
#/root   /   auto  defaults 0 0
```

(Note that the "/" must be the second tocken on the line)

And I also had to edit the /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf configuration file to remove (at least) "domain-name-servers" from the request list (but I removed many more, leaving only those I'm interested in, so I do not know if removing only this one is enough).

If you are interested in receiving domain-name-servers information from the DHCP server, then you may try to link /etc/resolv.conf to a read-write version (either in /run or /var/run or any other tmpfs place, but you'll have to create the file somewhere between the script which monts this tmpfs location and the script which sets up the network), or as a link to a file on a R/W filesystem.